# How to declare gluPerspective in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

How can I actually declare [gluPerspective](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml)?

I mean I am drawing a spiral and I am setting z = -50 in the beginning and looping until the circle is complete. So what will be the declaration of gluPerspective?

Comment: Do you mean "how to use gluPerspective" and not "how to declare"?

Comment: What platform? Programming language, operating system, version of OpenGL, etc.

Comment: thanks guys i got it somehow :)

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere at the top of the source file you want to use `gluPerspective` in:

```
#include <GL/glu.h>
```

and then you can use `gluPerspective` with no problem.

Comment: Sorry sir, we usually use the word declare over here, i might have gotten it wrong. Thanks neways

Comment: Ohh, ok, I think you mean the word "call" then. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean.`gluPerspective()` is typically used once when the program starts, then whenever the window is resized, to define the way primitives are projected to the screen.

You do that as so:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                        // Select The Projection Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                                   // Reset The Projection Matrix
    gluPerspective(60,screenWidth/screenHeight,0.1,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you have a look at the official OpenGL red book chapter 3, [Viewing](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name3). There you'll find a good introduction to perspective projection.

---

Edit after comment:

Well if you would read the chapter carefully you would read this:

> You can manufacture a viewing transformation in any of several ways, as described next. You can also choose to use the **default location and orientation** of the viewpoint, which is **at the origin**, **looking down the negative z-axis**.

and

> *void gluPerspective(GLdouble fovy, GLdouble aspect, GLdouble near, GLdouble far);*
>   Creates a matrix for a symmetric perspective-view frustum and multiplies the current matrix by it. fovy is the angle of the field of view in the x-z plane; its value must be in the range [0.0,180.0]. aspect is the aspect ratio of the frustum, its width divided by its height. **near and far values** the distances between the viewpoint and the clipping planes, **along the negative z-axis**. They should always be positive.

Comment: Yes sir, but what i din c newhere is that they say near and far but where am i actually viewing it from?
-ve side or +ve side. we need to know that dont we?

Comment: Yes sir, so i am viewing from the -ve Z rt?
so for example,, i am making a spiral, and my z i start from -50 and keeps on incrementing z by 1 till the whole circle is complete once so that i get a spiral... so how shud i use gluperspective?

Comment: That depends from which point you want to look at your spiral.

Comment: sir no, i saw in superbible they use near and far as -1 and 1, so?
it is negative isnt it? then y?